# Remap meta key to other key on the keyboard

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a programmable mechanical keyboard and can place any key anywhere.
At our company we recently switched to windows PCs and so that broke my emacs configuration because of the dreaded windows key which I tried to map to Meta but never got it to work.

Basically I use tigervnc to run vnc session that runs on linux.
Running emacs under linux in the VNC on a windows machine is a pain.
Every time I click the windows button to act as a meta the windows menu popup.

Anyways, I wonder if I can map Meta key to say "insert key", and the program the keyboard to have "insert" in place of "windows key" and vice versa.

I am also using ALT for other configurations so I don't want to map meta to ALT since I sometimes use all three combinations "Ctrl+ALT+Meta"+F-keys.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You may also wish to look at the variable `meta-prefix-char` which is normally mapped to the escape key.  Check out the default value before deciding whether you wish to change it to something else.  If you change it, it would need to occur at the outset of all your customizations so that libraries that load subsequent thereto are are aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you can tell us which keyboard you own. 
If it supports QMK firmware, you can just create two layers of keymaps for regular Windows usage and for VNC.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to peruse [Keymaps for Translating Sequences of Events](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html) (`function-key-map` et al).

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to map insert to meta I should do something like (define-key local-function-key-map "insert" 'Meta)

Comment: this is _not_ necessarily this simple. you will have to do some legwork.